# How are temporary suspensions by one's own request handled?

Tags: feature-request, account-suspension

In [this answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/194230/259412) I can see maybe it is possible, although I think it could be an over-use of the SE team. I think, they are for exceptional technical problems over the influence of the mods.

Maybe an automated solution could be developed for this?

If somebody asks for an irreversible, temporary suspension (if he has account on multiple SE sites, then network-wide), how is it handled? Is it even possible?

What is the best way to ask for this, if it is possible?

Also I think a suspension at one's own request shouldn't be counted as if it had been a punishment. In these cases, the punishment had been if the user hadn't been suspended.

Comment: To accomplish one now I suspect you can flag a mod to do it from any post, ask a mod in the Meta of that site or use [Contact Us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact).

Comment: @PolyGeo As I know, mods can suspend only regarding their sites, what can be impractical (and over-use) if somebody has many accounts. Furthermore, the suspension reason ("rule violation", "cool down") won't be true in these cases. Maybe a "for own request" could be inserted into the list.

Comment: I would suggest the text "this account is suspended to enjoy a holiday of XX days".